# Json format - scala

Tags: json, scala

I need to build a Json format in the following way in scala. How to implement the same ?

```
{
 "name": "protocols",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "tcp", "children": [
     {
      "name": "source 1",
    "children": [
     {
      "name": "destination 1",
        "children": [
     {
      "name": "packet 1"
     },
     {
      "name": "packet 4"
     }
   ]
     },
     {
      "name": "destination 2","children": [
     {
      "name": "packet 1"
     },

     {
      "name": "packet 4"
     }
   ]
     },
```

I need a tree structure like this to be wriiten to a file .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using play, your json structure can be represented with single case class

Here is a sample, where this case class is called Node

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Node(name: String, children: List[Node] = Nil)

implicit val format = Json.format[Node]

val childSource1 = Node("destination 1", List(Node("packet 1"), Node("packet 4")))
val childSource2 = Node("destination 2", List(Node("packet 1"), Node("packet 4")))

val source1 = Node("source 1", List(childSource1, childSource2)) 

val example = Node("protocols", List(Node("tcp", List(source1))))

Json.prettyPrint(Json.toJson(example))
```

Comment: What if I can't predict the number of source and destination..it could be like source 1 to source n?

Comment: Json format does not make any assumptions of children depth for the Node. So the depth of the tree does not matter, as long as format holds.

Comment: Thanks. Just one more doubt since I am very new to this.How to assign source1 , destination1 to values in code?

Comment: You mean deserialization?

Comment: No. In my code I am actually having variables  protocol ,source , destination ,for each packet. How to assign this to json variables?